# Promise memory leak solving

Tags: typescript, promise

I use to play with this function, I'm using a wrapper library https://github.com/colyseus/timer that allows to manage all my timer in one place and cancel them. The Clock instance has a `.clear` method that remove all pending timeout.

Here is my code that wrap

```
import BaseClock, { Delayed } from "@gamestdio/timer";

export class Clock extends BaseClock {
  /**
   * Return a promise that resolves after the duration
   * @param duration in ms
   * @returns
   * TODO: Add some mechanism to avoid dead promise if time gets destructed
   */
  duration = (duration: number) => new Promise((resolve) => this.setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}
```

now I can use `await this.clock.duration(10000).then(() => console.log("Do something"))`

But what if I call `this.clock.clear` before the timeout resolves? The `resolve` function will never be called. and I'll get a memory leak issue when a promise is awaited forever. This is edge case, and might not consume a lot of memory but still.

I don't think this is an issue when using this syntax :

```
this.setTimeout(() => console.log("Do something"), 10000)
```

has the callback will be removed by the garbage collector ?

Does anyone has an idea.

My goal is that when cleared i just want the promise to disappear like it never existed, or doing a noop.

Should i add some mechanism to the `.clear` method to send a resolve with an argument telling it's been aborted ? and in the `duration` method handle a no-op if this argument is true ?

Thanks

Comment: There are several things that (to me) don't look right there, up to the fact that you might be trying to solve a non-existent problem: AFAIK only DOM even handlers can create leaks if not removed, which is anyway not about releasing "the callback"...  Let me try and ask you an initial question: "what if I call this.clock.clear before the timeout resolves?", but how are you going to call `clear` if you are *awaiting* on `duration`?